# Integral over a complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, definite-integrals

I am wondering if closed-form solutions exist for the following integral:

$$\int_\mathbb{C}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-|v|^2}|v|^{2n}d^2v$$

where $u$ is a complex number, $c>1$ a real constant and $n$ is a positive integer.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since $n$ is a positive integer, you can simplify the integral by differentiation under integral sign:

$$\int_{\mathbb{C}} e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c} - |v|^2} |v|^{2n} d^2v
= \left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\right)^n\left[
\int_{\mathbb{C}} e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c} - \beta |v|^2}d^2v\right]_{\beta=1}
$$

Comment: This is due to the Leibnitz Integral Rule?  Very clever!!!

Comment: @achillehui I think I can use your method to find a closed-form solution for a more complicated integral: $\int_\mathbb{C}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-|v|^2}(v^*)^{n}v^md^2v$ where $v^*$ is a complex conjugate, since I think $\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-|v|^2}(v^*)^{n}v^md^2v=\left(-\frac{\partial}{{\partial}\alpha}\right)^n\left(-\frac{\partial}{{\partial}\beta}\right)^m \left[\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-\alpha\beta v^*v}d^2v\right]_{\alpha=1,\beta=1}$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Nope. For the more complicated integral, you need something like
$$\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-|v|^2}(v^*)^{n}v^md^2v
= \frac{\partial^{n+m}}{\partial\alpha^n\partial\beta^m}
\left[\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}- |v|^2 + \alpha v^{*} + \beta v}d^2v\right]_{\alpha=\beta=0}$$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for your help! So, can't you use a similar approach for my "simple" integral: $\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-|v|^2}|v|^{2n}d^2v$ $=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial\beta^n}\left[\int_{\mathbb{C}}e^{-\frac{|u-v|^2}{c}-(1-\beta)|v|^2}d^2v\right]_{\beta=0}$ to avoid having to keep track of whether $n$ is odd or even?

Comment: ??? $n$ in the simple integral is a positive integer. It can be an odd number too. Do you mean the in the integrand, replace the $2n$ part in $|v|^{2n}$ by an arbitrary positive integer? In that case, the integral will become ugly. It will no longer be expressible in terms of elementary functions. Instead, you will get some Bessel functions.